# Do rails custom validations halt the save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

Specifically http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

I feel like this isn't answered/documented properly. If you look at the example code -> all it does is call errors.add which according to this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-add
doesn't do much other except add the message to the errors.

Upon testing, it does halt the save but I will leave this here for people to find.

Comment: If there are errors then the model isn't valid.

Answer (score 1):

An object is saved to the database only if it is valid. Using 'errors.add(:attribute_name, error_message)' associates an error with the object making it invalid, resulting in the object not being saved.

Answer (score -1):

If an error exists on a field in an object (we'll call it "x"), then `x.valid?` is false. A failure of this validity check DOES prevent the object from saving. It will either return false if you call `x.save` (or `create(x_params)`), or raise an error if you call `x.save!` (or `create!(x_params)`). Raising errors is especially useful in the context of creating multiple record in a transaction, as that will break you out of the transaction and into your rescue block (assuming you allow for such).

Comment: I added an error once and was able to proceed to update the object using Object.update(attributes). the update method still went through even though the object had an error.